# What kind of a method is this and how does it work?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This method has a non void return yet it does not use the return statement at all.

Can someone explain whats happening here?

```
private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia,true),
};
```

Comment: Please prefer to read about java Arrays.

Comment: i can try to explain : you have posted an unclear question with not enough description

Comment: Yeah, I just worked on something for 12 hours straight, so my head was not in the right place when I asked this question.

Note to self: don't try to do anything while it's 5 in the morning and you're sleepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a method, it is a field which is directly initialized

Example:

```
class IHaveAnInitializedField {
    RandomClass a = new RandomClass();

    public RandomClass getA() { return this.a; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a method. It is a variable declaration. You create and initialize a `TrueFalse` array and assign it to the variable `mQuestionBank`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a method it is an array declaration with initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This code is trying to create **TrueFalse[]** array named **mQuestionBank** , where initilize 6 **TrueFalse** objects. It is not a method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of 6 TrueFalse objects